# monit does not find the unicorn worker in production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, unicorn, monit

I'm using this gem for deploy [kapify](https://github.com/ivalkeen/kapify).

This is my unicorn config:

[unicorn config](https://github.com/ivalkeen/kapify/blob/master/lib/kapify/unicorn/configuration.rb)

[unicorn.rb.erb](https://github.com/ivalkeen/kapify/blob/master/lib/generators/kapify/unicorn/templates/unicorn.rb.erb)

[unicorn_init.erb](https://github.com/ivalkeen/kapify/blob/master/lib/generators/kapify/unicorn/templates/unicorn_init.erb)

I have in my deploy:

```
server "111.111.111.111", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, 'myapp'
set :user, "hyperrjas"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "path_to_my_remote_reposytory.git"
set :branch, "master"
set :current_path, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}/current"
set :shared_path, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}/shared"

set :unicorn_workers, 1
set :unicorn_pid, "#{shared_path}/pids/unicorn.pid"
set :server_name, "myserver.com"
```

this is my pid in remote server:

```
ps aux | grep unicorn
1000      6037  0.4 12.5 320464 127628 ?       Sl   14:09   0:37 unicorn master -c /home/hyperrjas/apps/myapp/shared/config/unicorn.rb -D                                                         
1000      6079  0.2 13.8 335784 140828 ?       Sl   14:10   0:17 unicorn worker[0] -c /home/hyperrjas/apps/myapp/shared/config/unicorn.rb -D                                                      
1000      6322  0.0  0.0   9384   868 pts/0    S+   16:14   0:00 grep unicorn
```

this is my `config/deploy/templates/monit/unicorn.erb` file:

```
check process myapp_unicorn with pidfile /home/hyperrjas/apps/myapp/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
start program = "/etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp start"
stop program = "/etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp force-stop"

check process myapp_unicorn_worker_0 with pidfile /home/hyperrjas/apps/myapp/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.0.pid
start program = "/bin/true"
stop program = "/usr/bin/test -s /home/hyperrjas/apps/myapp/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.0.pid && /bin/kill -QUIT `cat /home/hyperrjas/apps/myapp/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.0.pid`"
if mem > 200.0 MB for 5 cycles then restart
if cpu > 50% for 15 cycles then restart
if 5 restarts within 25 cycles then timeout
alert myapp@gmail.com only on { pid }
if changed pid 2 times within 64 cycles then alert
```

I can see in monit the next path to unicorn worker pid:

```
Pid file /home/hyperrjas/apps/myapp/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.0.pid
```

And the message:

```
Status  Not monitored
```

The unicorn pid in remote server are in `/home/myapp/apps/myapp/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`

I can not see the pid `unicorn.0.pid` in `/home/hyperrjas/apps/myapp/current/tmp/pids/`

Monit is monitoring fine the unicorn pid.

**How can I monitorize with monit my unicorn worker?.**

Answer (score 1):

I used [this configuration](https://gist.github.com/shapeshed/1221753) when setting up monit to watch unicorn master and worker processes for three different apps on my Linode.  [This article](http://nebulab.it/en/nebulog/monitoring-unicorn-with-monit) walks you through the settings and how each thing works together.

I wouldn't recommend trying to generate the monit config for unicorn on the fly, rather, I'd tell unicorn to always write PIDs to the same file name in your app, then reference those files in the monit config.

Let me know if you get stuck, and I'll help you out.  Also, if my config would be helpful, let me know and I'll post that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm using this gem https://github.com/ivalkeen/kapify for deploy and all things is working fine except the monit for unicorn worker. I think that problem is that `Monit` can not see the `unicorn.0.pid` in `/home/hyperrjas/apps/myapp/current/tmp/pids/` folder. I have 2 files in this folder: `delayed_job.pid` and `unicorn.pid`. Thank you very much

Comment: This is likely because by the time you've deployed, the `current` directory has been re-symlinked.  Try poining unicorn to store the PID file in `/home/hyperrjas/apps/myapp/shared/pids` or something similar, as the `shared` directory won't change.

Comment: I have changed my pid folder to `/home/hyperrjas/apps/myapp/shared/pids` and I have the same problem: I can see in monit the red message `Execution failed` with my unicorn worker. I can see in monit `Pid file /home/hyperrjas/apps/myapp/shared/pids/unicorn.0.pid` . However I can not see this pid file in `/home/hyperrjas/apps/myapp/shared/pids/` In this folder only I can see 1 file: `unicorn.pid` Thank you very much!

Comment: I have added my unicorn config in my question. Thank you very much!

Comment: Read through this article and let me know if it helps, specifically, the "after_fork" section:  http://www.stopdropandrew.com/2010/06/01/where-unicorns-go-to-die-watching-unicorn-workers-with-monit.html

Comment: Thank you I have tried with this fix but I have the same problem :(. Thank you for your help!